# php str_replace array quotation marks

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to use php str_replace on an array of some words, but I met a problem when str_replace uses quotation marks. `dell’ex` still returns `dell’ex`...

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$txt = "Violenza sessuale e sgombero dell’ex ambasciata somala: la punizione collettiva non è una soluzione"; 
$txt= str_replace(array(',','.','-','\'','\"'),'',$txt);
$txt = str_replace(array('á','à','ó','ò','é','è','í','ì','ú','ù','È','É'),array('a','a','o','o','e','e','i','i','u','u','e','e'),$txt);
echo $txt;
?>
```

Comment: Probably it is an apostrophe and not a single quote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ’ is nowhere to be seen in your replacement array, only ' is in it ( ’ vs ' not the same character). And you don't have to escape the double quotes ( " ) if you're putting it in single quotes.

try :

```
$txt= str_replace(array(',','.','-','\'','"', '’'),'',$txt);
```

if you want to keep only alphanumeric characters, maybe something regexp based is a better solution :

```
$txt = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $txt);
```

This code will replace anything that isn't a capital letter, a letter or a number.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should understand that `'` and `’` are visually different, so they must be pragmatically different.

try:

```
$txt = str_replace(array('’',',','.','-','\'','\"'),'',$txt);
                          ^
```

- `&rsquo;` = `’`